# Starting with Go Templates, what does the T indicate in {{T "post_nav_prev"}}

Tags: go, hugo

Trying to understand Go templates in Hugo.  I find the subject construct {{T "post_nav_prev"}}. I see post_nav_prev defined in i18n yaml file en.yaml, but can't seem to find what T is or where it is defined.  Sorry for the lack of basic knowledge.  Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is an alias for `lang.Translate`

source : https://gohugo.io/functions/lang/#langtranslate

It define [here](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/e164834f0aaaf1c58489fab41f5835b66f16b87c/tpl/lang/init.go#L33)